# Stripe one-time payments, why the code does not work

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, checkout

Why the code is not working? After calling redirectToCheckout should be redirected to checkout at stripe website. I receive empty website instead.

```
<head>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?
require_once('stripe-php-master/init.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_Qh1r4ukQPIvXAkzCzTzRuaZP004NBFnoVT");

$object = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'success_url' => 'https://www.example.com/success',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://www.example.com/cancel',
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => [[
        'amount' => 500,
        'currency' => 'gbp',
        'name' => 'T-shirt',
        'description' => 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
        'images' => ['https://www.example.com/t-shirt.png'],
        'quantity' => 1,
    ]]
]);

$session_id = $object->id;

if ($session_id) {

    echo "<script>
          var stripe = Stripe('sk_test_Qh1r4ukQPIvXAkzCzTzRuaZP004NBFnoVT');
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: '" . $session_id . "'
          }).then(function (result) {
          });
          </script>";

} else {

    echo 'No Session ID!';

}
?>
</body>
```

Here is the source of the output

```
<head>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
          var stripe = Stripe('sk_test_Qh1r4ukQPIvXAkzCzTzRuaZP004NBFnoVT');
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: 'cs_test_Kmy6jtaQd3JDDAOZR1lPVo5CyrIOx7XM0FsDfTFmBL5d8t4qlo8zrSwc'
          }).then(function (result) {
          });
          </script></body>
```

I am ok with programming in PHP. But JS is not what I understand well. 
Thanks

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: You do not have a function after .then(function (result) {

Comment: Do you see anything in your browser console when you load your page? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console